# Apache wildcard subdomains with url masking

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to handle wildcard subdomains with url masking in apache.
Correct rewrite rules should achieve the following:

`http://demo.system.dev` to `to http://system.dev?subdomain=demo`

`http://sample.system.dev/user/edit/100` to `to http://system.dev/user/edit/100?subdomain=sample`

`http://debug.system.dev/project/edit/new` to `to http://system.dev/project/edit/new?subdomain=debug`

So far i have the following rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.system\.dev
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://system.dev%{REQUEST_URI}?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

which looks like its working ok except that the browser url is also changed. I would like the browser url to remain the same and internally route the request but i am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @anubhava its the same domain actually, the site-available file is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)subdomain= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.system\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $0?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: when i type http://system.dev/user/edit/100 it loads ok but when i type it with the subdomain http://demo.system.dev/user/edit/100 its redirected back to http://system.dev

Answer (score 1):

You can not internally rewrite to another domain. So when you go to your subdomain it will redirect to main domain as you have it. So you will need to use relative URL and see if that works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?system\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.system\.dev [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: tried it and i keep getting 500 Internal Server Error with message 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.', thinks its probably redirecting in loops

Comment: I added a few more checks to make the rule more robust. Also check your error log to see what message it gives.

Comment: changes doesnt help either, i keep getting a 500 error, apache logs say 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://demo.system.dev/user/edit/100'